# Should I fork Ruby on Rails on Github for a OpenSource RailsApp?

Tags: github, fork

Playing with the idea of developing a small opensource rails app which then in a later state will be deployed to heroku.

Should I fork the [Rail git-repo](http://github.com/rails/rails) and work on my fork or do I see this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fork if you plan to make changes to the code. Are you really going to change Rails itself?